# What modules in the Linux source code take care of hot-pluggability?

Tags: linux, kernel, hot-plug

Could someone shed more light on the code/modules that are responsible for the hot-pluggabilty of the hardware used in Linux machines?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look into [udev](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/hotplug/udev.git). There's a similar question on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28613/how-does-automated-hotplug-mounting-work).

Comment: udev is the binary right? I wanted to know which modules in the source code take care of hot-pluggability.

Comment: It depends on the type of device. USB device additions and removals are detected by the USB driver, which [notifies](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/usb/core/notify.c) udev about changes.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer from Iain Dawson](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49881/73) covers the userland part. In the kernel proper the handling of hotplug is integrated all over the place. Some infrastructure is present in the base kernel, but hotplugging has to be handled in each device driver, so there is no set of modules responsible for this.